# SVM image prediction Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, svm

I've extracted some features from images in my train dataset, then I've applied those features and split the data into train and test using `train_test_split`:

```
Train data  : (60, 772)
Test data   : (20, 772)
Train labels: (60,)
Test labels : (20,)
```

What I want to do next is apply the SVM classifier to my images in the test dataset and see the results.

```
# create the model - SVM
#clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=40)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=10000.0, gamma=0.0001)

# fit the training data to the model
clf.fit(trainDataGlobal, trainLabelsGlobal)

# path to test data
test_path = "dataset/test"

# loop through the test images
for index,file in enumerate(glob.glob(test_path + "/*.jpg")):
    # read the image
    image = cv2.imread(file)

    # resize the image
    image = cv2.resize(image, fixed_size)

    # predict label of test image
    prediction = clf.predict(testDataGlobal)
    prediction = prediction[index]
    #print("Accuracy: {}%".format(clf.score(testDataGlobal, testLabelsGlobal) * 100 ))

    # show predicted label on image
    cv2.putText(image, train_labels[prediction], (20,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, .7 , (0,255,255), 2)

    # display the output image
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()
```

I'm not getting very good accuracy with this, even though I can see that it says 60% accuracy. Yet most of the images are incorrectly labeled. Have I passed a wrong argument in the `prediction`?

What can I do to improve this?

**EDIT**: I've tried what you said with the following code, but I get an error saying I should reshape my `feature_vector`. So I do that, and then I get the following error.

(As a reference: `feature_extraction_method(image).shape` is `(772,)`.)

```
for filename in test_images:

    # read the image and resize it to a fixed-size
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    img = cv2.resize(img, fixed_size)

    feature_vector = feature_extraction_method(img)
    prediction = clf.predict(feature_vector.reshape(-1, 1))
    cv2.putText(img, prediction, (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, .7 , (0, 255, 255), 2)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()   

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-2b8ff4146d8e> in <module>()
     19 
     20     feature_vector = feature_extraction_method(img)
---> 21     prediction = clf.predict(feature_vector.reshape(-1, 1))
     22     cv2.putText(img, prediction, (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, .7 , (0, 255, 255), 2)
     23     plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in predict(self, X)
    546             Class labels for samples in X.
    547         """
--> 548         y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
    549         return self.classes_.take(np.asarray(y, dtype=np.intp))
    550 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in predict(self, X)
    306         y_pred : array, shape (n_samples,)
    307         """
--> 308         X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
    309         predict = self._sparse_predict if self._sparse else self._dense_predict
    310         return predict(X)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py in _validate_for_predict(self, X)
    457             raise ValueError("X.shape[1] = %d should be equal to %d, "
    458                              "the number of features at training time" %
--> 459                              (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
    460         return X
    461 

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 772, the number of features at training time
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your code.

First, you don't need to classify the whole test set in each interation of the for loop. Predicting the class label of one image at a time would suffice:

```
    prediction = svm.clf.predict([testDataGlobal[index, :]])
```

Notice that `testDataGlobal[index, :]` must be enclosed in square brackets `[ ]` as the `predict()` method expects a 2D array-like variable.

Second, and most important, let us suppose that the function `glob` yields a list of three image files, namely `imgA.jpg`, `imgB.jpg` and `imgC.jpg` and let us denote their corresponding feature vectors as `featsA`, `featsB` and `featsC`. For your code to work properly it is essential that `testDataGlobal` is arranged as follows:

```
[featsA, 
 featsB, 
 featsC]
```

If the feature vectors are arranged in a different order you are likely to get wrong results.

You could correctly label the images through the following snippet (not tested):

```
test_images = glob.glob("dataset/test/*.jpg")

for filename in test_images:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    img = cv2.resize(img, fixed_size)
    feature_vector = your_feature_extraction_method(img)
    prediction = svm.clf.predict([feature_vector])
    cv2.putText(img, prediction[0], (20, 30), 
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, .7 , (0, 255, 255), 2)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()
```

where `your_feature_extraction_method()` stands for a function that consumes an image and returns its feature vector (1D array-like).

**Note**: Don't forget to enclose `feature_vector` into square brackets `[ ]`. You could also use any of the following approaches to increase the dimension of `feature_vector` in one more dimension:

```
    prediction = svm.clf.predict(feature_vector[None, :])
    prediction = svm.clf.predict(feature_vector[np.newaxis, :])
    prediction = svm.clf.predict(np.atleast_2d(feature_vector))
```

Comment: Thank you!! I tried what you said but I get an error (see **Edit** above). Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I missed to enclose `feature_vector` into square brackets in the call to the `predict()` method. Thank you for spotting this. I've just edited my answer and now the code should work fine.

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-96-8e8dcbb06af1> in <module>()`
     
`---> 23     cv2.putText(img, prediction, (20, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, .7 , (0, 255, 255), 2)`
`TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation`

Comment: It gives me an error in the `cv2.putText` - it doesn't accept `prediction` as an argument

Comment: Also, if it `print(prediction)` to see what the output is, for every image it gives me `[1]` which is `Landscape`..But it shouldn't be the same for all images

Comment: `prediction` is an array of one element. You should pass `prediction[0]` to `cv2.putText()` to fix that error. The most likely reason for the classifier to assign the same class label (`1`) to all the images is that data contained in `trainDataGlobal` or `trainLabelsGlobal` (or both) are flawed. You should also try out different values for `C` and `gamma`.